# Curl unable to resolve host (Localhost behind a proxy server)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, proxy, facebook-php-sdk

Following exception was thrown while trying to execute `$facebook->api('/me')`

> Uncaught CurlException: 6: Could not resolve host: (nil); Host not found thrown in C:\wamp\www\demo\php-sdk\base_facebook.php on line 1027

I figured out that my localhost was unable to resolve **graph.facebook.com** because my localhost runs on machine connected to my college network which is behind a proxy server.

One of the solutions I thought of that I need to forward all the requests made by my web application to my localhost to the network proxy server and then retrieve and process the result at localhost.

Kindly suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Later I used VPN (HotSpotShield)